# Checkbox on change is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I got a check box on the html page as:

```
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk-info" name="chk-info"  />
```

when I try to write an on change event and run, it's not getting fired. Instead if, I place an alert message before the function it is firing fine.

```
 alert('blah');
 var sth = function(){
 function m(){
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function (e) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert("true");
            } else {
                alert("false");
            }

        });
   }
     return{ m:m};
    };
```

I have tried using the id selector as well, but with not much luck.
Can anyone help me in pointing where the issue is?

**EDIT: When I place the check box checked function outside the above function it works well with 'onchange' event attached on the `<input>` tag**

Comment: Just tested this and everything is working fine, is this all the code you have ?

Comment: No, I got other functions in the same page as well and I don't see any errors on the browser console. I got this event placed on the page load as well.

Comment: Could you add the complete Javascript code ? What are you doing to the checkbox ? Is this the only part of the code that interacts with your checkbox ?

Comment: if the checkbox is checked I need to hide a div content, that's all the JS code that is available.

Comment: Well, the code you have provided works on my computer. So there are no problems with it. I am certain that something is happening in your other code. Go and create a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the onclick event of the checkbox on page load.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="chk-info" name="chk-info" />
<label for="chk-info">label</label>
```

Comment: This should work, but it's not good practise to add a click handler on a checkbox to check if it has changed. The checkbox could also be checked/unchecked via label, in which case this callback will not fire.

Comment: I have updated label for the checkbox (above code) and the code still runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).val("true");
        } else {
            $(this).val("false");
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="chk-info" name="chk-info" />
<label for="chk-info">label</label>
```